# Как закрыть терминал в Windows не убивая процессы

Tags: windows, cmd, процесс, командная-строка

Есть ли в Windows какая-то возможность открыть терминал, запустить процесс и закрыть терминал не убивая сам процесс? Что-то типа nohup

Comment: А зачем его вообще открывать и закрывать? Сразу в фоне нет? Погуглите "аналоги демонов под виндой" =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843903/how-to-start-daemon-process-from-python-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Команда `start` должна помочь

```
start progname.exe
```

Comment: Мне нужно использовать это для консольных приложений. Например, с типом .py, которые выполняются в консоли, а не исполняемые файлы типа .exe. При этом мне нужно иметь возможность закрыть окно терминала, не убивая выполнение процесса

Comment: А консоль вы показывать при этом не хотите?